# Please add the subscriber count for a tag to the info and questions pages for that tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki, subscription

When I hover over a tag with a mouse, I get a quick count of the number of tag subscribers.

[image: Tag hover - subscriber count]

This information is not displayed on either the landing page for a tag or the "learn more..." page for a tag. (I couldn't find this anywhere accessible from the iPad - but perhaps I'm just not aware of where to find this count using a touch device that lacks a mouse)

Can the subscriber count (or lack of subscribers) be added to top right of the tag page [.../questions/tagged/tag_name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) ?

Can this count also be added on the [.../tags/tag_name/info page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info)? Adding this to the top or embedding it in the "stats" section on the right margin might be a nice place for the current subscriber count.

Comment: Device doesn't matter - i want that on my laptop all the time, it's easier to have everything in one place.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and edits - the mobile aspect is the least important factor in this request. Having subscriber count revealed directly on the pages as opposed to being a "hidden" element seems reason enough to ask that this be considered. Mobile not being able to find the data seems like icing on the cake than the nub of the issue.